# PHP Xero API > Create Invoice not receiving customer address details

Tags: php, contacts, xero-api

I'm having an issue with XERO Api when creating invoices. It all works fine apart from the addess and contact number do not pull through to XERO. Below is the code I'm using. There are no errors and the contact is created and invoice email sent just no address details. Can anyone see anything I'm missing?

```
        
       
         
        $xeroTenantId = $this->Storage_model->getSession()['tenant_id'];
        
        
        if ($this->Storage_model->getHasExpired()) {
            $provider = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
            'clientId'                => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
            'clientSecret'            => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
            'redirectUri'             => 'xxxxxxxxxx.co.uk/callback',
            'urlAuthorize'            => 'https://login.xero.com/identity/connect/authorize',
            'urlAccessToken'          => 'https://identity.xero.com/connect/token',
            'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => 'https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Organisation'
          ]);

            $newAccessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('refresh_token', [
              'refresh_token' => $this->Storage_model->getRefreshToken()
            ]);

            // Save my token, expiration and refresh token
            $this->Storage_model->setToken(
                $newAccessToken->getToken(),
                $newAccessToken->getExpires(),
                $xeroTenantId,
                $newAccessToken->getRefreshToken(),
                $newAccessToken->getValues()["id_token"] );
          }
        

        $config = XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setAccessToken( (string)$this->Storage_model->getSession()['token'] );
        
        $apiInstance = new XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Api\AccountingApi(
              new GuzzleHttp\Client(),
              $config
          );
            
           
        
            $idempotencyKey = rand()."IDDEMP";
            $summarizeErrors = true;
            $unitdp = 4;
            $dateValue = new DateTime('now');
            $dueDateValue = new DateTime('now');
            $dueDateValue->modify("+1 month");
            
            //test data
            $contact['firstName'] = "Fred";
            $contact['surname'] = "Blogs";
            $contact['email'] = "Fred@test.co.uk";
            $contact['contactNumber'] = "079671111111";
            $contact['billingAddress1'] = "Address 1";
            $contact['billingAddress2'] = "Address 2";
            $contact['billingAddress3'] = "Address 3";
            $contact['billingAddress4'] = "Address 4";
            $contact['billingPostcode'] = "DT94XX";
            
            //[add a contact]
            $setFirstName = $contact['firstName'];
            $setLastName = $contact['surname'];
            $setEmailAddress = $contact['email'];
            $setContactNumber = $contact['contactNumber'];
         
             $address = array(array(
                'AddressType' => 'STREET',
                'AddressLine1' => $contact['billingAddress1'],
                 'AddressLine2' => $contact['billingAddress2'],
                'City' => $contact['billingAddress3'],
                 'State' => $contact['billingAddress4'],
                'PostalCode' => $contact['billingPostcode']
            ));
         
        
            $contact = new XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Contact;
            $contact->setName($setFirstName." ".$setLastName)
                ->setFirstName($setFirstName)
                ->setLastName($setLastName)
                ->setEmailAddress($setEmailAddress)
                ->setContactNumber($setContactNumber)
                ->setAddresses($address);
          
            $arr_contacts = [];
            array_push($arr_contacts, $contact);
            
            $contacts = new XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Contacts;
            $contacts->setContacts($arr_contacts);

            $apiResponse = $apiInstance->createContacts($xeroTenantId,$contacts);
            //[/add a contact]
            $lineItems = array();

            $lineItemTracking = new XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\LineItemTracking;
            $lineItemTracking->setTrackingCategoryID('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000');
            $lineItemTracking->setTrackingOptionID('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000');
            $lineItemTrackings = [];
            array_push($lineItemTrackings, $lineItemTracking);
            
         foreach($order as $value) {
            $lineItem = new XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\LineItem;
            $lineItem->setDescription($value['rowTitle']);
            $lineItem->setQuantity($value['rowQty']);
            $lineItem->setUnitAmount($value['rowPrice']);
            $lineItem->setAccountCode('200');
            $lineItem->setTracking($lineItemTrackings);
            array_push($lineItems, $lineItem);
         }
            

            $invoice = new XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Invoice;
            $invoice->setType(XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Invoice::TYPE_ACCREC);
            $invoice->setContact($contact);
            $invoice->setDate($dateValue);
            $invoice->setDueDate($dueDateValue);
            $invoice->setLineItems($lineItems);
            $invoice->setReference($contact['reference']);
            $invoice->setStatus('AUTHORISED');  //$invoice->setStatus(XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Invoice::STATUS_DRAFT);
         
        
        
            $invoices = new XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Invoices;
            $arr_invoices = [];
            array_push($arr_invoices, $invoice);
            $invoices->setInvoices($arr_invoices);
            
        
            try {
              $result = $apiInstance->createInvoices($xeroTenantId, $invoices, $idempotencyKey, $summarizeErrors, $unitdp);
              $data = XeroAPI\XeroPHP\AccountingObjectSerializer::sanitizeForSerialization($result);
             
                //email invoice
                $requestEmpty = new XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\RequestEmpty;
               
                try {
                    $idempotencyKey = rand()."IDDEMP";  
                    $apiInstance->emailInvoice($xeroTenantId, $invocieID = $data->Invoices[0]->InvoiceID, $requestEmpty, $idempotencyKey);
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                      echo 'Exception when calling AccountingApi->emailInvoice: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
                    }
                
            } catch (Exception $e) {
              echo 'Exception when calling AccountingApi->createInvoices: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
            }
            
        echo "complete";
        
    }
```

Comment: Your code looks correct but I've not been able to test. To provide some context, the SDK converts the objects that you are creating and converts it into a JSON payload which is then sent within an API call.
If we can look at the JSON that is generated we can then check it. If you can get in touch with api@xero.com and include the ID that should have been included in our server response we'll be able to check our logs to see what happened.

Comment: If anyone else was having a issue with the address not showing on the invoice. I changed "'AddressType' => 'STREET'" to "'AddressType' => 'POBOX'" and this worked